# Get logs of a function separately each time it is iterated in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, pyspark

I have a `pyspark` script like below. In this script I am looping through a `input` file for table names and executing the code.

Now I want to collect the logs separately each time the function `mysql_spark` is iterated.

For example:

`input file`

```
table1
table2
table3
```

Now when I execute the `pyspark` script I am having logs for all the three tables in a single file.

`What I want is 3 separate log files 1 for each table`

`Pyspark` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

#Condition to specify exact number of arguments in the spark-submit command line
if len(sys.argv) != 5:
    print "Invalid number of args......"
    print "Usage: spark-submit import.py Arguments"
    exit()
args_file = sys.argv[1]
hivedb = sys.argv[2]
mysqldb=sys.argv[3]
mysqltable=sys.argv[4]

def mysql_spark(table, hivedb, mysqldb, mysqltable):

    print "*********************************************************table = {} ***************************".format(table)

    df = sqlContext.table("{}.{}".format(mysqldb, mysqltable))

    df.registerTempTable("mytempTable")

    sqlContext.sql("create table {}.{} as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))

input = sc.textFile('/user/XXXXXXXX/mysql_spark/%s' %args_file).collect()

for table in input:
    mysql_spark(table, hivedb, mysqldb, mysqltable)

sc.stop()
```

`Shell` script to invoke `pyspark` script file run.

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/$USER/mysql_spark/source.sh
[ $# -ne 1 ] && { echo "Usage : $0 table ";exit 1; }

args_file=$1

TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log
success_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
failed_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log

#Function to get the status of the job creation
function log_status
{
       status=$1
       message=$2
       if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | tee -a "${failed_logs}"
                exit 1
                else
                    echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [INFO] $message [Status] $status : success" | tee -a "${success_logs}"
                fi
}

spark-submit --name "${args_file}" --master "yarn-client" /home/$USER/mysql_spark/mysql_spark.py ${args_file} ${hivedb} ${mysqldb} ${mysqltable} 

g_STATUS=$?
log_status $g_STATUS "Spark job ${args_file} Execution"
```

`Sample log file:`

```
Connection to spark
***************************table = table 1 ********************************
created dataframe
created table
delete temp directory
***************************table = table 2 ********************************
created dataframe
created table
delete temp directory
***************************table = table 3 ********************************
created dataframe
created table
delete temp directory
```

`Expected output`

`table1.logfile`

```
Connection to spark
***************************table = table 1 ********************************
created dataframe
created table
delete temp directory
```

`table2.logfile`

```
***************************table = table 1 ********************************
created dataframe
created table
delete temp directory
```

`table3.logfile`

```
***************************table = table 1 ********************************
created dataframe
created table
delete temp directory
shutdown sparkContext
```

How can I achieve this?

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new file and write data into that for each iteration.

This is a simple example:

```
lis =['table1','table2']

for table in lis:
    logfile = open(str(table)+".logfile",'w')
    logfile.write(str(table))
    logfile.close()
```

In you code if you implement same concept and pass the file object to mysql_spark function for every iteration it should work.

```
for table in input:
    logfile = open(str(table)+".logfile",'w')
    mysql_spark(table, hivedb, mysqldb, mysqltable, logfile)
    logfile.close()
```

Comment: Using your code I am able to create the log files but the files are empty one with no log information.

Comment: Yup, but you have the file object, you can check the conditions and write what ever you required in that file object.

Comment: for example:
df = sqlContext.table("{}.{}".format(mysqldb, mysqltable))

if (df):
 logfile.write("Sql Context Created.")
else:
 logfile.write("Sql Context Not Created.")
 
Something like this.

Comment: Actually in the log files I want to have the console output.